# Directly upload CSV file from third party site

Tags: javascript, csv

I am trying to have a CSV file automatically upload to the back end when it is generated using a link from a third party site. For example, if you look at the available players in my fantasy football league (https://www.fantrax.com/fantasy/league/kg59suyejg6n1zg0/players) you'll see an option to download the CSV file. I want to be able to take that link and instead of saving the file locally either directly open the CSV file in the client or send it directly to the back end. Just as a slight complication, CORS headers are disallowed so I can't use an axios request.

I'm simply looking for a JavaScript way to open said file in the browser or save it to the remote location instead of locally.

Comment: Seems overly complicated to try and do this via the browser. Why not analyze the csv-fetching link and figure out how to directly hit that endpoint in your backend code? You might even figure out a way to programmatically get your data without any manual intervention week to week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could automate the downloading sequence (e.g. headless browser + Node), and run this as background service.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#node
https://blog.phantombuster.com/web-scraping-in-2017-headless-chrome-tips-tricks-4d6521d695e8

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the downvote is for, seems like a d1ck move, but I'm going to post the code that actually did what I need it to, though I was directed toward the idea of using  headless browsing from kimbrys.  It's hacked together a bit because I was just trying to get something working.  As a note, I'm using Django on the back-end so I had to play around a bit with selenium for Python instead of node, and I also went away from downloading the csv because I'm ultimately going to be hosting this and I don't know that I can "download" a csv to the server on which it's being hosted.  This way I can at least have an endpoint direct to this script that will work in the background.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

os.system('cls')

t0 = time.time()
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath('''C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'''), chrome_options=chrome_options)

results_per_page = 500
max_page = 8
try:
    full_list = []
    for page_number in range(1,max_page+1):
        print(f'''page_number {page_number}''')
        driver.get(f'''https://www.fantrax.com/fantasy/league/kg59suyejg6n1zg0/players?view=STATS&positionOrGroup=ALL&seasonOrProjection=PROJECTION_12_235_SEASON&timeframeTypeCode=YEAR_TO_DATE&transactionPeriod=1&miscDisplayType=1&sortType=SCORE&maxResultsPerPage={results_per_page}&statusOrTeamFilter=ALL_AVAILABLE&scoringCategoryType=5&timeStartType=PERIOD_ONLY&pageNumber={page_number}&schedulePageAdj=0&startDate=2018-09-06&endDate=2018-12-30&searchName=&txs=false&teamId=hvnwk9ryjg6n1zqi''')
        names = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'scorer__info__name')))
        positions = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'scorer__info__positions')))
        for name, pos in zip(names, positions):

            pos = pos.text.replace("\n","")
            position = pos.split(',')[0].split('-')[0]
            team = pos.split('- ')[1]
            full_list.append([name.text, position, team])
finally:
    player_list = []
    position_list = []
    team_list = []
    for entry in full_list:
        player_list.append(entry[0])
        position_list.append(entry[1])
        team_list.append(entry[2])
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([player_list,position_list,team_list]),columns=['Player','Position','Team'])
    df.to_csv('Player_database.csv',index=False)
    driver.quit()

print(time.time() - t0)
```